# How to put background for UITableViewController

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad, background, uitableview

I wanna do something like [THIS](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/21367418/online-post/paper-uitable-view-controller.png) in my ipad application, what is the best way to do the followings:

1. The shadow under the upper bar.
2. The padding for the papers (top, left, right & bottom)
3. The background (as a notepad) : please think about the cells: they must still scrolled inside the paper and cropped before reaching to the paper bottom edge.

I'm looking for the optimal solution that avoids overriding as much as possible.

**EDIT** :

I tried to use UIViewController (with UITableVIew and has the delegate methods) inside UISplitViewController, And I tried adding UIImageView at the top of the table but this view will scroll with the cells and it'll hide when I scroll down. I tried to use viewForHeaderInSection function also for upper shadow (under the bar) but what about the papers bottom edge (what if I put one image including the shadow and the papers bottom edge and has the padding as a background for the UITableView or UITableViewController, and change this image when rotate to the portrait orientation? is this a good and possible solution?)

Comment: so, what have you tried?

Comment: Please, check the question again, I updated it with more details

Answer (score 0):

My guess:

- Create the background in an image editing app
- Cut 4 images, for header, footer, left and right sides
- Create a UIViewController with 4 UIVIews and add the correct images as background
- In the middle of all 4 add a UITableView

This way the images won't move and if you position the UIViews with the background properly, your TableView will scroll inside the notebook (assuming you are trying to create a notebook)

If you app is iOS 6.0 only, autolayout will be a great help. Check apple developer video on it to learn how to use this feature: [WWDC 2012 Session 232 - Auto Layout by Example](http://developer.apple.com/itunes/?destination=adc.apple.com.16351493766)

Answer (score 0):

One easy way to do this is from the xib:
1. In xib create image .On image view you can put background whatever you want as a image.
2. create table view above the image view and set table view background color as a clear color.

This will do it.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I prefer not to add full image as a background, I think it's not the best scenario, what I'm looking for (if possible) to add one small layer (UIImageView,...) at the top and another at the bottom of the table instead of adding full bg image. ............ The top will be a 1 px gradient png file for the shadow effect & the bottom will be a ~10 px for the papers edges and this two layer will displayed above the table and stick in trier position while the table is scrolling